# Anonymous method with return type IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

I'm designing a search engine for my website. Read search key and return data.

My test code:

```
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<TopicViewModels> GetTopics(List<TopicViewModels> topics)
{
   foreach (var item in topics)
   {
      yield return item;
   }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<TopicViewModels>> Search(string key)
{
   try
   {
      using (var db = new MyDbContext()) //EF
      {
         var topics = await db.Topics.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(key)).ToListAsync();
         if (topics != null && topics.Count > 0)
         {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetTopics(topics));
         }
         ErrorMessage = "No topic was found.";
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       ErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

I'm looking for a solution that I can use `GetTopics` method as an anonymous method. No need to create new method to get all topics because no more another classes/methods reuse `GetTopics` method.

But my problem is: `yield return` cannot be accepted in anonymous method. Just like:

```
var topics = await db.Topics.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(key)).ToListAsync();
topics.ForEach(x => 
{
   yield return x;
});
```

So, my question is: Is there another way to do it better?

**UPDATE: (Based on @EricLippert comment)**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TopicViewModels>> Search(string key)
{
   using (var db = new MyDbContext())
   {
      var topics = await db.Topics.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(key)).ToListAsync();
      if (topics != null && topics.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (var topic in topics)
         {
            yield return topic;
         }
      }
      ErrorMessage = "No topic was found.";
      yield return null;
   }            
}
```

Error syntax message:

> The body of 'TopicMaster.Search(string)' cannot be an iterator block
>   because `Task<IEnumerable<TopicViewModels>>` is not an iterator
>   interface type

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TopicViewModels>> Search(string key)
{
   var topics = await new MyDbContext().Topics.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(key)).ToListAsync();
   return topics != null && topics.Count > 0 ? topics : null;
}
```

Comment: I am confused by the question. You already have an `IEnumerable<T>` in hand. Why do you need the `GetTopics` method to turn a sequence into another identical sequence in the first place?

Comment: And for that matter, why are you running `GetTopics` asynchronously? I don't understand why the body of the `if` isn't simply `return topics;`. You have the sequence in hand; return it!

Comment: Another point.  I don't think `ToListAsync` would return `null`.  Or more specificly a `Task<List<T>>` where the `Result` that you get from the `await` would be `null`.

Comment: @EricLippert I just edit the method based on your comment.  But I'm getting syntax error now. Please help!

Comment: No, just get rid of all that yield nonsense. You don't need it.  `if(whatever) return topics;` done.  Why do you think you need to yield anything?  **You already have a sequence**.

Comment: While we're looking at your code: it's a bad code smell to have a method that produces a sequence return null as an error condition. If you have an error condition, throw. If you want to eat the exception, return an empty sequence. Don't both eat the exception and return a reference that someone then later on has to check for nullity before enumerating. That's just asking for a null reference exception in the future.

Comment: Also change your `yield return null` to `return null` if you want a `null` sequence or better yet `return Enumerable.Empty<TopicViewModels>()` to return an empty sequence like Eric recommends.

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry. I've updated it.

Comment: @juharr Thanks! I've done it in the update 2.

Comment: You should still put the context into a `using` statement to make sure it's disposed of properly.

Comment: @HappyCoding: You're welcome. Remember, the whole point of "await" is to try to make asynchrony simpler. If you feel like you're having to jump through a lot of hoops to satisfy the type system, take a step back and ask if those hoops are really necessary. Most of the time things should just work, we hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Eric's saying:

```
if (topics != null && topics.Count > 0)
{
  return topics;
}
```

Specifically, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can just return the list. There's no need for an iterator block, or an anonymous delegate, or `Task.Run`, or `foreach`/`ForEach`.